# how to close navigation properly before go to new Activity class

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

I want to hide `NavigationView` before go to new activity . In this time in my app **Navigation Drawer** not hiding properly yet start new activity . So I want to hide navigation properly then go to new activity .And I am not using number of fragment with activity. I am using total activity with **navigation drawer**.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
```

if you want to close drawer and then launch another `Activity` add delay using `Handler`

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //launch activity here
            }
        },TIME_IN_MILLI_SEC)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try closing your drawer when a item is selected:

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
      new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
          @Override
          public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
              menuItem.setChecked(true);
              //saving the id of the item selected
              itemSelected = menuItem.getItemId();
              mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
              return true;
          }
});
```

Then you can use a `DrawerLayout.DrawerListener`. On the `onDrawerClosed` you can start your Activity

```
@Override    
public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
        if (itemSelected >= 0) {
            Class activityClass = null;
            switch (itemSelected) {
                case R.id.itemId:
                    activityClass = MyActivity.class;
                    break;
                //same for any other item
            }
            if (activityClass != null) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, activityClass);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
```